# bash: exchaning value of rows by expression

Tags: bash

I guess this is quite a simple question, but I am trying to edit my data before I import it to R. I would like to this in the terminal, to make it fit my pipeline.

For each row in my dataset, if $4 > $5, I want to swap around the values and set $7 = "-".

I was thinking to do a for loop. In R i would look a bit like

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    while(df[i,4]>df[i,5]){
        tmp <- df[i,4]
        df[i,4] <- df[i,5]
        df[i,5] <- tmp
        df[i,7] <- "-"
    }
}
```

So that:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    1       100     .   +   .
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    300     200     .   +   .
```

would be changed to:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    1       100     .   +   .
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    200     300     .   -   .
```

How would I do that in bash?

Example of my data:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    11869   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "ENST00000456328.2"; nearest_ref "ENST00000456328.2"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "ENST00000456328.2"; nearest_ref "ENST00000456328.2"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    13221   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "3"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "ENST00000456328.2"; nearest_ref "ENST00000456328.2"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    11869   12057   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.5"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    12179   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.5"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "3"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.5"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    13225   13655   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "4"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.5"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    13661   14412   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "5"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.5"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    11869   12057   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000004"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.4"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    12179   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000004"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; oId "CUFF.12.4"; nearest_ref "ENST00000450305.2"; class_code "j"; tss_id "TSS1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
awk '{if ($4 > $5) {t=$4; $4=$5; $5=t; $7="-"; print} else {print}}' data
```

However, it will destroy some of the whitespace between the columns. Not sure if that's a problem to you.

Comment: In my original data the data is tab-seperated, so I guess that wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Ah, that makes it easier. Add `-v OFS='\t'` as an option to awk, and the output in the modified lines will also have tabs as separators.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`.

Like

```
awk '{tmp=$4; $4=$5; $5=tmp; $7="-"; print;}' dataset.file
```

Comment: How can  I implement that in a script give me a file where every row where $4>$5 has changed and all other rows are unchanged?

Comment: This line - using your file in place of `dataset.file` - should do exactly the same. If you do not want to change column 7 to a dash (-) anymore, then leave out the `$7="-";` part. If you want to use the output, just pipe it into anything else.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed an important point. Please see Georg P. 's answer above.